# Particle lifetime doesn't depend upon longitudinal momentum

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, particle-detectors

I am writing a report on an analysis of the $B_{s}$ meson from CDF data, and as part of the lifetime analysis, I have noted down that:

$$\tau = \frac{l_{xy} m_{B_{s}}}{p_{T}}$$

Where $l_{xy}$ is the transverse displacement from the primary beam vertex, $m_{B_{s}}$ is the observed mass of the $B_{s}$ candidate, and $p_{T}$ is the transverse momentum of the $B_{s}$ candidate.

However, I did this a long time ago, and it is no longer obvious to me why the proper lifetime of the $B_{s}$ candidate does not depend upon $l_{z}$ or $p_{z}$. Could anyone share any illumination on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper lifetime of the $B_s$ does not depend on anything. [OK, it's a survival probability distribution, from the oscillations of the $B_s$, but for these purposes here it is the independent variable.] It is the l$_{xy}$ that depends on $\tau$. Clearly, $l_{xy}$ is a distance and should equal the speed times the time:

$$l_{xy} = v_{xy} t = \beta_{xy} c \gamma\tau = {p_T\over E} c {E\over m}\tau = {p_T\over m} c\tau$$